# How to display sum stack bar in echarts with legend handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

What I need is to show the totals above each column and for the total to be recalculated as the legend is shown or hidden. What is the best practice to do this?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

In this code example the total is calculated through a bar below those that are generated through echart, what I want to achieve is that the total of the bar below is recalculated every time the legend is modified

```
let result = 0;
let array = [];

const series = [
    {
      name: 'Direct',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [320, 302, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
    },
    {
      name: 'Mail total',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
      name: 'Affiliate total',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
    },
    {
      name: 'Video total',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [150, 212, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
    },
    {
      name: 'Search Engine',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [820, 832, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
    },
  ];
  
  sum()

option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      // Use axis to trigger tooltip
      type: 'shadow', // 'shtotalow' as default; can also be 'line' or 'shtotalow'
      label:{
        formatter: function (params){
          for ( let i = 0; i < params.seriesData.length-1; i++){
            result += params.seriesData[i].value
          } 
          let resultFinal = params.value + " -------------------- total: " + result
          result = 0;
          return resultFinal;
        }
      }
    }
  },
      legend: {
        data: series.map(item => item.name),
    },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Direct',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [320, 302, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
    },
    {
      name: 'Mail total',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
      name: 'Affiliate total',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
    },
    {
      name: 'Video total',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [150, 212, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
    },
    {
      name: 'Search Engine',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [820, 832, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
    },
    {
    
      name: ' A total of ',
      type: 'bar',
      tooltip: {
        show: false
      },
      stack: '',
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      label: {
        normal: {
          show: true,
          position: 'right'
        },
      },
      data: array,
      z: -1,
      barGap: '-100%',
    }
  ]
};


function sum(){
  for ( let z = 0; z < series[0].data.length; z++){
    for( let i = 0; i < series.length; i++){
    result += series[i].data[z];
  }
  array.push(result)
  result = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, We will not be able to help with this kind question if you don't provide a minimum reproducible code example. Try put yourself in any other person shoes. read your own question and ask yourself would you or anybody else be able to answer this question if they didn't know anything about how this graphs are rendered judging by two screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to detect when the legend is clicked/changed, by using `'legendselectchanged'` event.  Once the legend is changed, you can recalculate the array of results and then push this new array to your chart.

Add the following code to the example you gave and it'll work. ([Working example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=DYUwLgBATiDOCuxIF4IAYDcBYAUKSAhlFAQJ4SoDaAutjrgMYD2AdrJLCFAJZwUSVcEYRADeQkcJYEAtiABcEAOQARbjAZglAGgmSwpAA4LlAIyI69I9gQYBrRUrBMwBYJZyThwAqZDBFcU8vYVgACyYAd0UwKHgQK2EAX11gyRAZQzCCWG5YQMSRADMmBnh85U4eOCVClMKAEwJXRUoAZgAmNG0INrQOnr6ARkG2gBZBgE5u3r7BruorerSxQuk5RwBZAm5gCGdXd1SQg2NHcygPEJt7RwO3K68fPwDVlclwqJi4hPeIZZCGSyOTyBT-whKZQqSiqvFgtT-AK8TRaAiGXR6Q06mLQIwgWImEGmPQ6cwgHSGaEWKyRwiCIXWJiUAEEikVdtxmiB9i4HscvKcmRdHh9XLdlPcjoVnv4wSFQhFovsfnV-elMtlchV6fLIeVHLCaqrGs0CK0Ohj8QAOAb4yZ40mEjrE2YzNqU6mSWlvBmyJkANW4DRATB5hxFIkF5wsausYocEt5Ur-MteOuuiu-8WNfyBmtBPt1pX1lS4cIRIW9whRZrRAFYZhTbV08UM64Shi62mSxh6lrH0yJGY4AMogIgMMIQACiLAA5twWCAI8Io2YY4UbgmnEmVxBU3L5Z8lbFs4jY8I8yDtYUIcXoYb4TmQjXWjaZlbsUTcT1JuNMc6MxYmSWILP2Ei0BIEgIDIAAUACUuC4EwhhgNwrD8DqzhMEg3CGIeq48HOc5cI4BAAB55BGFF5AACkwi5gKRhaSAA9KxEAAKqcBANGwDyyrcMRXA8jhaGGIUa4wtkDRRDoEDsZUYSSnJvH8cGRQEIgYAYBADAECwvHALAoZ-MowCLsuEBMFASkqZEFZPL4sqDpIJRQDIzRMVAihFPALCaOhhmwYYRCyLA8GuV47kQLB-7gBA3D8JgiUQAAPBAoUkDIsAAHSPiopq5aA85gGEAC0Qy6dwADUNWRbeXgwAgSAQDVqBZeF-VlnAhWuJQ3DULlABubhnvKIhJBAjXeAlzXaQAYoubj8J1OUjWN3I1RAABEEDlQdh1Hcdx1hm4ih7dt81IDN0BwNpyV0BNwgwGA8BQIZ11gEt0jAE98pJHUSwSFW8UkSwDQEcipqKI-uWeYYsHcExMgUAAfIlKO5Yy8Gxkic48JDLHxUUYCOG0ACkEZEcpjhjFTsamC4zgyOTDNWMwLCuIuAAyzmvKevzJPy5HMpRN4rFJo3APEjlIqQYsFoOUn6Uxc42aQEavgISibKw8lKAAKrLPRKAA6iADQG4bYTwAbC08AbI7NE7_lKJ6_z8o-rRWFFw7KGoGhaBe-xGEKG5_Fudy7iHB7Ex8mbKuNXig1eWpQ2594Gj1T7niaqLtJafS2sMoyEm0XZkp0VLgSsft-lsOx7JKe5ScKIdR4m4ax_zGfWIngvPl4adK41eoPjnjleiH2uUOiQFfpSrb_t-JJkhSNc0gOawN8orLshZXJncmJxh9Glwd_G0fd9Kvfx_3XxJ0LKchyPEsTeP2fVLnlYzzDAgWiAjaTE9o15Okrm6PsW9fY7w2MoQMwZQwtxDm3CO1wr5dz5LfF4fcFSP0HnnXMGpry4IgJ_Us38p6TT_gXNsjZ0Qkh_PidsIC3Q9igdPGBfx_ZKDHBOKcs4FxLlbmfdcF9NwYJ3DfFMd8op4JPCqQhgJiHp3vneKEX9yxD0kLPd8PRPy2mmHiP8HZAKYm7AvMC0C65WFgUyCAzJj7WSKMoFBoilDt0kkwMSeFSHHl8m4Tg2i4y2G3HuZgwAbKOAAMQLTifEvccc5EQBYDZTyaZbr-KfiHSQhgmC5DQqwRwNMtCNVBqDbWRASCkBDgAL0UJVEOFwADiBB8LKEqmgNA7MaQQVwEkOgSEcB-QCoUwyMEEI6hinFfAEBamPTmelCAj5KBUlyjWYqIBSphF0rUuqDUVjuRmQlJKqAUpJQynDEqc4yrVX2YOL6bVUArMGus00lBamQWCIDYIVSyC5UMOUMIsEvqIWCI8s5_0fk_NwDIUgABhbIUAwC5VYLBJQoBwYNE4KATQk4DIkStj0EZgUMIhTCjleChY_mkE2ds5KEhpnxUgPMyFizLk51WUNDZ1zblzPuVYI5zLUpsoucsnOdKbk7MSgKv43AijkuynlHFIBNCW0oC8oajJqBgomo89q4rv4DW5e8z5_1khWBpQCoFIL7pIF1SICF6AoUSDhYiogKLOBgAAPKoSCrBFCYz4J0CSMGoAA))

```js
myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function (params) {
  array.length = 0
  for ( let z = 0; z < series[0].data.length; z++){
    for( let i = 0; i < series.length; i++){
      if(params.selected[series[i].name])
        result += series[i].data[z];
    }
    array.push(result)
    result = 0;
  }
  myChart.setOption(option);
});
```